# When to extent the web application

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-application, extended

what is the best practice to choose whether to extend your web application?

When we need to make our web Application as a public website for public users and keep one for portal admins, and when have the same web application for both.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the requirement:

1)if you require your application to have different authentication type.

2)Or you have diffent target user for your application.

Basically by extending WebApplication you create a new Site IIS Site with same application with same/different configuration for WebApplication.